# How to append a letter after a counting up number?

Tags: jquery, count, append

I'm not a javascript person.

I'm trying to make a counting number with "%", "x" or "Million" for my website. Like a feature number show. (Example: http://valiancecap.com/)

I'm using Squarespace and included jquery and counterup.js in the head section.

The following code allows me to do the count up number:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586653108315_12058 p').counterUp({delay: 20,time: 2000});
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586650859535_18885 p').counterUp({delay: 20,time: 2000});
</script>
```

But If I add append after that, it shows NaN.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586653108315_12058 p').counterUp({delay: 20,time: 2000});
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586650859535_18885 p').counterUp({delay: 20,time: 2000});
    $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586650859535_18885 p').append( "x" );
</script>
```

So my situation is count up itself is working, append itself is working. But it's not working when it's together.

I hope someone can help me with it.

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Renjie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `counterUp()` function expects a number and nothing more, so it stops working when you add a character or symbol to the element containing the number.

If you are able to edit the HTML, then something like this should work:

```html
<div id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586650859535_18885">
  <p><span class="counter">0</span> millions</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586650859535_18885 .counter').counterUp({delay: 20,time: 2000});
</script>
```

Comment: OMG, that was a perfect clean solution!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you don't mind, and if this answers your question, would you consider reading [this short guide on what to do with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Oh ~ Sorry, I didn't know the rule. I think I accepted the answer. I'm not sure if I vote it right. Because when I hit the vote button it says 15 reputation something... Thank you again.